# SCNShadable protocol gives internal error during fragment function compilation on newer devices

Tags: ios, metal, metalkit

We have written a shader modifier based on the [SCNShadable protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable) which works well until the number of uniform variables is rather slow (say 5-10). Later we needed to extend the shader modifier and use new uniforms, a total number of 25, including 8 textures and corresponding float4x4 matrices. Then it stopped working, could not compile the fragment function, which gave the following useless error message:

```
Error Domain=AGXMetalA12 Code=3 "Internal error during fragment function compilation" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Internal error during fragment function compilation}
```

When we reduced the number of `float4x4` matrices to 2, it started to work again on an `iPhone 7` and other `Metal GPU Family 3` devices, but not on `Metal GPU Family 4` or newer devices.

Our question is if someone knows any limitations that explain this kind of behaviour.

Comment: Nondescript internal errors are always bugs and should be reported as [feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com). In the meantime, you could try setting a symbolic breakpoint on the `newLibraryWithSource:options:error:` method and printing the source that's being passed to the compiler by SceneKit. It can be tedious to narrow down such errors, but perhaps inspecting the source will yield insights toward a workaround.